# Texture problems with Character movement

Tags: libgdx

Ok I am developing a game using Libgdx and everything was fine until I noticed that when my character moves, its texture becomes slightly blurred at the edges, as if it is blending in with the background in the android version. There seems to be a slight graininess to the image as well which becomes more noticeable when it moves. I THINK these problems might be related to texture filtering, but wanted to come on and ask here to see if anyone had experienced this before. Any insight appreciated.

EDIT: Here is an the image, you can see it's quite grainy on the whole. When it moves the graininess seems move, it is hard to describe, but it looks as if the pixels on the eater are moving relative to each other slightly.

[image: grainy picture]

The way I draw it is pretty straight forward the following is called in my render method:

```
idleTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/GreenGuy.png"));
spriteBatch.draw(idleTexture, x, y*ppuY,width*ppuX,height*ppuY);
```

All other work I look at does what I am doing, but I am not totally happy with the results. I have tried changing between linear and nearest filtering but this did not change anything. I have also tried just using a smaller image instead of shrinking a large one, but I still get the same problem of the pixels not remaining relatively static while the character is moving.

Comment: Add a picture and add some code. We are not magicians and can see what you have done. And if You think it is the filter, did you try without the filter?

Comment: @BennX Sorry was hoping it would be a common issue, will add what you mentioned soon.